# Correct usage of 'would have'

Tags: idiomatic-language, literature

In Lord of the Rings The Two Towers king Theoden says the following line:

**Saruman's arm would have grown long indeed if he hopes to reach us here.**

As a non native speaker I would have said it like this:

**Saruman's arm would have to grow long indeed if he hopes to reach us here.**

I wonder if the first sentence is idiomatic and if it makes sense. It feels a bit off to me. Can anyone explain?

Just as a reference, the official translation on my language would be something like this translated back to English:

**Saruman is wrong if he thinks he can reach us here.**

Comment: The first sentence is not 'off'. Theoden is saying that Saruman's arm would need to have already grown (in the past) 'long indeed', if it is true that he hopes (in the present) to reach Theoden and the others.

Comment: Tolkien was Professor of English Language and Literature at Merton Collge, Oxford for 15 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, Tolkien's sentence is (we can assume) exactly what he intended to write.

The structure is a conditional: If it is true that Saruman hopes to reach 'us' then Saruman's arm would need to have already grown very long. Of course the reference to his "arm" is figurative.

That makes sense.  If your arm is short then you don't hope to reach very far.

The style is "heightened".  Tolkien's characters, especially his kings, elves, and wizards speak in a "noble" style, in contrast to the Hobbits who are plain speaking.

Comment: Do you have any grammatical reference for this kind of usage? Because I only know of it being used in a third conditional, but there the conditional part should be in the past(if he hoped) and here it is in the present(if he hopes). Generally it is answering something that didn't happen in the past so a sentence like 'If I hope to finish college, I would have studied.' Doesn't make sense to me, and Tolkien's sentence is in the same category.

Comment: The "first second third" conditionals are a teaching aid, to help you learn that not every use of the past tense in a conditional sentence actually refers to the past. Native speakers rarely use these terms (they aren't taught in English lessons at school, for example).  If you want lots of detail on grammar then any of the "weighty" grammars would probably discuss conditionals (eg Cambridge Grammar of the English Language). In this case the use of a conditional is to imply it's contrapositive.  "Saruman's arm would not have grown long, so he does not hope to reach us here."

Comment: posted a related question here https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/317931/idiomatic-mixed-conditional-sentences              if the sentence from Tolkien is idiomatic how do you explain the related question's sentences? Which grammar rule fits the Tolkien's sentence?