# Idiomatic mixed conditional sentences

Tags: conditional-constructions, conditionals

This is related to my other [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/311968/correct-usage-of-would-have).

So I went to look up mixed conditionals and the sentence from the linked question fits the form of 'present condition/past result' conditional. Now the rules say that the verb should be in past simple tense for the 'present condition' part. In the linked question the users said that the sentence is idiomatic, but the verb is in present simple tense.

So of the following two sentences which one is idiomatic:

> If I **hope** to finish college, I would have studied.
>
> If I **hoped** to finish college, I would have studied.

Comment: hope always points to the future: I hope he will arrive on time. If I hope to finish college, I will have to study. The past one is OK.

Comment: The first is wrong, see comment above. The second doesn't sound very good either. The following might work: 1- "If I hoped to finish college, I would study." [implied: but I don't have any hope, so I won't study] 2- "If I had hoped to finish college, I would have studied." [implied: but I lost hope at some point in the past so I didn't study]

Comment: @cruthers so how would you explain the correctness of the sentence in the linked question?

Comment: The Tolkien sentence is in an elevated style in which no one speaks, and is even hard to interpret for a native speaker without context (which I don't have). There's an idiom that is used nowadays: "If you hope to X, you should/must Y." It explains what you need to do to achieve something. That's how "if you hope to" is typically used in the present tense. Tolkien appears to be using "hope" more literally - i.e. if someone currently has hope that he can do something, a condition must be present.

Comment: And, furthermore, Tolkien's choice to phrase the condition as "would have grown long" instead of the more idiomatic (at least in present day) "must have grown long" is itself unusual.

Comment: @cruthers oh I just noticed I wrote this sentence incorrectly, the hope verb is not even there. Goes like this: **Saruman's arm would have grown long indeed if he thinks he can reach us here.** Does this change anything about the idiomaticity of the sentence?

Comment: Ah, ok. Nowadays, "must have grown long" is far more idiomatic. That's the normal way of expressing that a past event necessarily happened, even when there is an "if" conditional. "Would have" for this purpose sounds very dated/elevated to me.